# Set Object key as variable in Javascript with Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass a variable as the param to vue-router so it can be set dynamically. Pretty much as the example below:

```
<router-link :to="{ 
  name: notification.name,
  (notification.param_name): notification.param_value
}">Blabla</router-link>
```

I am not looking at setting the key like this: `var[notification.param_name]`.

I suppose this question could be expanded to a more general problem, but I am having a hard time explaining it in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be simplest to make it a computed which returns the definition of the route based on the `notification` object (note that you need to specify the params inside the `params` property of the object):

```
computed: {
  notificationRoute() {
    let { name, param_name, param_value } = this.notification;
    return { name, params: { [param_name]: param_value } };
  }
}
```

And bind that to the `to`:

```
<router-link :to="notificationRoute">Blabla</router-link>
```

Comment: Thank you. The actual answer I was looking for was `[param_name]:`. Although, making the route computed seems wise!

Comment: Yeah as a general rule, if I'm passing anything inline to a component that needs to be more than one line, I define it as a computed property instead.